# std::chrono::system_clock + now() to milliseconds and back different behavior

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm a bit puzzled to find a portable way to convert milliseconds to `std::chrono::system_time::time_point`. I looks like the code :

https://godbolt.org/z/e7Pr3oxMT

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto now_ms = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now);

    auto value = now_ms.time_since_epoch();
    long duration = value.count();

    std::cout << duration << std::endl;

    std::chrono::milliseconds dur(duration);

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> dt(dur);

    if (dt != now_ms)
        std::cout << "Failure." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Success." << std::endl;
    

    return 0;
}
```

should work the same on win32 and linux. But unfortunately on windows (msvc) I'm getting `Failure` as output.
Please, assist to understand what is wrong ?

Comment: Most likely, you need to replace `long duration = value.count();` with `long long duration = value.count();`.  In windows, `long` is only 32 bits wide, while it is 64 bits wide in the Nix world.

Comment: Rather than using `long` or any other integer type, you can use `std::chrono::system_clock::rep` as the type. It provides an arithmetic type that can correctly store the result of `count()`. Or you can just use `auto duration = value.count();`.

Comment: if you look up documentation, you will not find any function in c++ stadnard library, which returns a `long` - Instead they use values like `size_t` or `uint32_t` and you should stop using "naked integer types" in your code.

Comment: Simply change `long duration` to `auto duration`, as it shouldn't be your intention to perform an implicit cast here.

Comment: Oh, damn! My mistake...thanks for comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably

```
long duration = value.count();
```

The type `long` isn't necessarily 64 bits wide. The C++ standard does not define the exact size of integer types besides `char`. Visual Studio uses 32 bits for `long` even in an x64 build, for example.

Anyway, try

```
uint64_t duration = value.count();
```

in your code or just

```
auto duration = value.count();
```

Comment: Yep, thanks for comment. As I mentioned in comments, I did a stupid mistake while porting from linux.